# Ggplot2: Label X-Axis To be What I Want Insted of What It Is

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want the `x-axis` to be labeled with elements of the `lb` column from the dataframe `df1`.

```
df1 <- read.table(text =
                    "method1  9 0.2402482
                     method2  9 0.1023012
                     method3  8 0.2031448
                     method4 4 0.2654746
                     method5 9 0.4048711")

colnames(df1) <- c("Methods", "lb", "RMSE")

df1 |>
  dplyr::mutate(colour = forcats::fct_reorder(Methods, RMSE)) |>
  ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::aes(Methods, RMSE, colour = colour)) + 
  ggplot2::geom_point(size = 4) + 
  ggplot2::geom_segment(aes(Methods, xend = Methods, yend = RMSE, y = 0)) + 
  ggplot2::scale_color_manual(values = c("green", "yellowgreen", "yellow", "orange", "red")) + 
  ggplot2::theme_bw() + labs(color = "Method")
```

Here is what I have is [image: the first image below]

What I actually want looks like [image: the second image below]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `labels` param of the `scale_x_discrete()` function, like this:

```
df1 |>
  dplyr::mutate(colour = forcats::fct_reorder(Methods, RMSE)) |>
  ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::aes(Methods, RMSE, colour = colour)) + 
  ggplot2::geom_point(size = 4) + 
  ggplot2::geom_segment(aes(Methods, xend = Methods, yend = RMSE, y = 0)) + 
  ggplot2::scale_color_manual(values = c("green", "yellowgreen", "yellow", "orange", "red")) + 
  ggplot2::theme_bw() + labs(color = "Method") + 
  ggplot2::scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) df1[df1$Methods==x, "lb"])
```

[image]

Comment: Adding `scale_x_discrete(labels = df1$lb)+` will be enough?!

Comment: Yep, in this case that is true @TarJae.